# RESTful Verify Password service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I'm writing a Verify Password service using the ASP.NET Web Api.

The service accepts a password for the currently signed in user, verifies it, and returns an encoded value. This all happens over SSL.

Calling this method causes no changes to state.

Initially this looks like it should be a `GET` request however on further inspection I'm concerned about the web server logging plain text passwords.

We could implement this as a `POST` but that seems like the wrong verb given the action.

Is this simply a case of pragmatism over procedure or is there more we can do to fulfil both the pragmatic and RESTful cases?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) where you pass the username/password as headers. This also fits better as the standard already defined.

There is already a [javascript](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) code for doing base64 encoding - if you need to do this on the browser.

---

If you are doing this to authenticate and the encoded value is the access token (cookie), it is better to use OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Aliostad. Looking at the Basic Auth details it's not quite what we need (the disadvantages list in particular). We're not actually signing the user in, we're simply checking if the currently signed in user knows their own password (a password barrier when changing some settings).

Answer (score 0):

If the API call sends a response that is not a resource per se (does not involve a resource returned from a data store), you should use verbs not nouns.

You can have a UserPasswordsController controller that exposes an action method like this:

```
[HttpPost()] 
public HttpResponseMessage Validate()
{
    if (!this.Request.Content.IsFormUrlEncodedContent())
    {
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
            "Body of request must be form URL encoded."
        );
    }

    var parameters  = this.Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;

    var userName    = parameters["userName"];
    var password    = parameters["password"];

    // TODO: Validate user name and password
    var isValid = true;

    if(!isValid)
    {
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, 
            String.Format(null, "The password provided for {0} is not valid.", userName)
        );
    }

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

And have a registered route like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name:           "UserPasswords",
    routeTemplate:  "api/v1/validate",
    defaults:       new { controller = "userpasswords" }
);
```

You would POST forms data to the validation endpoint that contains the user name and password you wish to validate. A status of Forbidden status indicates the password is invalid, while a status of OK is returned if the password is valid.

If you are new to working on REST interfaces and want to take a pragmatic approach, I highly recommend you take a look at [Web API Design - Crafting Interfaces that Developers Love](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf).